# Get a month's first day in a string(Monday,Tuesday) in php

Tags: php, date, calendar

I've been trying to get the first day in a string of a month.
I have two variables:

```
$year = 2016;
$month = "November";
```

And I want to get the first day of November of 2016(that is Tuesday).
I have tried

```
$string = "$year-$month-01";
echo date("l",strtotime($string));
```

And also

```
$string = "$year-$month-01";
echo date("l",$string);
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting about UTC timezone offsets relative to your location. Minimal fix for your code is to use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

```
<?php

$year = 2016;
$month = "November";

$string = "$year-$month-01";
echo gmdate("l",strtotime($string));
```

> Tuesday